# How do I reinstall Windows 10 File Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-explorer, uninstall, onedrive

I want to uninstall Windows 10 File Explorer, then reinstall it. How do I accomplish this task?

*Motivation:* Every time I navigate to my `C:\Users\MyUserID\OneDrive - Business\Documents\` directory two things happen:

1. The `C:\Users\MyUserID\OneDrive - Business\Documents\` folder is opened in my current instance of File Explorer.
2. An additional File Explorer occurrence spawns with the following path; `C:\Users\MyUserID\OneDrive - Business\` (one level up from the previous directory).

Action #2 above is unwanted, and I just close the window (constantly). This #2 behavior started after I installed One Drive. I can't find any way to disable action #2 above either. Uninstalling and reinstalling OneDrive didn't help.

With most things Windows it seems the only solution is to uninstall, then reinstall. But is it even possible with File Explorer?

Comment: You cannot, it is an integral part of Windows.

Comment: Sound like an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Randomhero yes it is, but I already asked separately the "X" and nobody has a clue how to solve it. I'll upvote you anyway because you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I tried for over a year to fix a bug like this (and could not).  I reinstalled (over the top, not fresh) windows, did SFC /scannow.. etc etc.

For me, it appeared to be a problem somewhere in HKCU because if I logged in as another user, it didn't happen.  I am betting that it is a rogue shell extension.

I eventually found the  [following batch file](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/17707-reset-folder-view-settings-default-windows-10-a.html)  and added a few lines of my own.

It would make the problem go away for a while.. until it came back.  Then I would run it again.

It might help you.

`

```
@echo off

::kill explorer.exe
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

:: To reset folder view settings of all folders
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F

Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\BagMRU" /F

Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F

Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /F

:: To reset "Apply to Folders" views to default
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults" /F

:: To reset size of details, navigation, preview panes to default
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\GlobalSettings\Sizer" /F
Reg Delete "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Modules\NavPane" /v ExpandedState /F

:: restart explorer
start explorer.exe
```

`

Comment: What does this script do? I am hesitant to run a registry editing script on my computer.

Comment: It resets all of the shell based persistent data like window positions and the like on windows.  It resets or deletes nothing else.  If you are afraid of it, please don't run it.