# Win 10 One of two screens only maximizes windows and shows 50%

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution, window

I got a really nasty and annoying nut to burst here. Maybe grab a coffee and snack since the story may get a bit long.

TL;DR: User has two screens and only one screen shows 50% of content in random windows that are maximized or some windows turn blank.

Here we go. Everything started with our migration. We are about 16-20 users in now and only this one has the issue. We put in place a temporary laptop until her's arrived that already worked perfectly fine with someone else and was in the wrong OU before. (OU = Organizational Unit)

The setup is this. Laptop to USB-C Docking with connected then 2 Screens of 1920x1080, Ethernet, Wireless USB Mouse and Keyboard. This setup works fine for most users and only some of them have to plug in the USB directly to the laptop because the docking is not yet allowed on those devices.

However for this user the docking was allowed and everything works. Now comes a bit of history. First we wanted to connect 2 4K screens of which only one could run with 4k 60hz while the other one only went as far as 1920x1080 60hz (I think. Maybe only 30hz). We checked if it was maybe an accidental resolution swap but nope. Only one screen can run on 4k.

Then we swapped the screens with 2 1920x1080 screens and then it started. She noticed this maybe a week in and we are since trying to figure it out. So next thing we tried was to swap the laptop as soon as her laptop arrived. There again is the issue.

Next we swapped the docking station, which of course also didn't solve the issue.

Meanwhile we also tried to fix the issue by changing the resolution from 1920 to 1620, applied and then from 1620 to 1920 to see if it was maybe a 4K mixup. We thought so because when we moved the windows with Windows-Key + Arrow Down the window came back and we were able to work with it. So we thought the windows got maximized to 4K instead of 1920.

Then we swapped the screen that had the issue with a brand new out of the box screen. You can guess it. No change. After a few minutes or hours it happened again.

So by now she has basically a whole new setup and we also physically switched the screens so the left screen was on the right and the right was on the left but this only shifted the issue from the right screen to the left screen.

Next we tried another solution from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/8imjva/windows_10_multi_monitor_maximized_window/e6jpu6i/) that I found randomly. I selected "Maintain Screen Scaling" instead of "Scale Full Screen" since it is the same setting my colleague and the screen that worked had. It worked for another few hours and then it came back.

By now the only think that came into my mind was that maybe in the appdata could be a screen setting that got stuck but there I couldn't find anything about a folder or settings that were saved in there.

The only thing we haven't yet tried is to remove all the graphic drivers to see if that may fix the issue but the problem is the laptop needs to work again and we aren't too keen to fubar it.

Any ideas, sugguestions or tips will be more than welcome.

**Edit:**

While looking some more I remembered that we actually connected the two 4K screens onto the old AND new laptop of that user. So I figured that it may be something related to the settings saved in the registry and found a somewhat useful arcticle.

[Screen Cache reset via Registry](https://winaero.com/blog/clear-reset-external-display-cache-windows-10/)

I also found this article which may also be of use if it helps us to prevent a reset of the machine.
[Screen settings reset with CTRL + Alt +F8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108927/ctrl-alt-f8-disconnects-displays?rq=1)

I tried both tips in that order on the old laptop but since I am not working constantly on that machine I cannot see which of the two fixed the issue in case that it is fixed now.

Comment: You might be dealing with the windows positions and sizes being remembered from before you added the new monitors.  Try [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1492576/how-do-i-reinstall-windows-10-file-explorer/1492598#1492598) on one of the machines to see if it solves your problems.  It blows away the screen positioning settings (and nothing else).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I don't think that we have access to make changes to the registry as sugguested by post. I can try but I am not very optimistic that it will work