# Double clicking a folder in file explorer launches a completely new file explorer process

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems

When attempting to open folders in Explorer, a completely new Explorer process is launched instead of the folder opening in the original Explorer process; this newly launched Explorer process **does not open in the target folder that was double-clicked on**, instead opening to Quick Access, with the original Explorer process not changing to the target directory opened.

How can I prevent this from happening and restore Explorer to its default behavior?

I've:

1. force killed and restarted `explorer.exe` through TaskKill
2. restarted Windows 10
3. confirmed *Browse Folder* option is set to *Open each folder in the same window*
4. reset all Explorer options to default
5. installed the latest Windows update, then rebooted

---

Additionally:

- Right-clicking a folder in Explorer shows default bolded action is *Open* not *Open in new window*
- `HKCR\Folder\shell\Default` string value: not set
- `HKCR\Folder\shell\open\Default` string value: not set
- `HKCR\Folder\shell\open\MultiSelectModel` string value: `Document`
- `HKCR\Folder\shell\open\command\Default` string value: `%SystemRoot%\Explorer.exe`
- `HKCR\Folder\shell\open\command\DelegateExecute` string value: not set

Comment: I myself have had this problem from a corrupt user profile.

Comment: See the post I wrote [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1492576/how-do-i-reinstall-windows-10-file-explorer/1492598#1492598).  For me this was only a band aid but let me know that it was indeed registry corruption.

Comment: It could also be a third part shell extension (but probably not in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following registry key, set the data for `DelegateExecute` to `{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}`

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command
```

[image]