# Win10 FileExplorer: how to undo the setting of a view template for a single folder and its subfolders?

Tags: windows-explorer

In the past I chose to customise a certain folder's view so that it would be 'optimised for general items', and I also checked the box for 'apply this template to all subfolders'.

I now simply wish to undo my decision to enforce the general items view template on this one folder and its subfolders, so that FileExplorer goes back to selecting whatever view template it sees fit for them. Can anyone help?

I do not mind if all user view customisations for this folder and subfolders are reset to defaults.

To be clear, I do not want any view templates to be modified themselves, or the view settings of other folders to be affected.

P.S. It's a folder with frequently changing subfolders, so manually setting a template  for each pre-existing and new subfolder is not the solution. As I say, I want FileExplorer to go back to auto-choosing the template based on folder contents.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all replies, but I have found a partial fix for undoing my setting of "Optimise this folder for: General items" and "Also apply this template to all subfolders", which is good enough for my purposes.

I opened up the folder's  properties, went back to the Customise tab, and unchecked the "Also apply this template to all subfolders" box and pressed OK.

While the root of the folder still has the General Items template enforced on it, any subfolders, whether pre-existing or new, have reverted back to the default behaviour of FileExplorer auto-selecting the view template as it sees fit based on content.

This may be good enough for others in this position, if as with my folder, the root only contains folders or otherwise general items anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are a limited number of folder kinds, as shown below:

[image: Folder kinds]

By default, **all** folders are *General items*, so your initial effort actually made **no change** in that folder's type, nor in its subfolders, **unless one or more of the folders was of another specific type**, i.e., *Documents*, *Pictures*, *Music* or *Videos*.

If that *is* the case, e.g., one of the folders contained *Videos*, then you have two choices:

- Change *all* the folders and subfolders to *Video*.

  - Right-click the top-level folder.
  - Select *Properties*.
  - On the *Customize* tab, select *Videos*.
  - Select *Also apply this template to all subfolders*.
  - Click *OK*.
- If you want to set each subfolder to its original kind, then there is no shortcut, AFAIK, to simply remove the folder's kind. You'll need to do as above for **each subfolder, without setting *Also apply this template to all subfolders***, unless those subfolders also contain the same kind of material.

Comment: It's a temp folder that frequently has subfolders added and removed, and they will contain all sorts of files. Is there no way to undo all user customisations for a single folder and all subfolders, so that FileExplorer will go back to automatically applying what it thinks is the best template for each subfolder and the root?

Comment: Save its contents, then delete the *temp* folder. Create a new temp folder, perhaps with a different name to be sure Windows does not perseverate.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved this problem for other reasons (corrupt profile).

I *would* list this as a duplicate but your problem is VERY different even though the solution is the same.

Windows keeps these settings in the registry under "stuff" called shell bags.
The script I provide in the following link will wipe them all clean.

Feel free to edit the batch script and comment out the parts you don't think that you will need.  I have commented the "code" so you should be able to follow what it is doing.

If you want to look at my script and figure out which of the gajillion entries are the ones you want be my guest.  I might.. but really, I would probably wipe it all out and start again.

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1492576/how-do-i-reinstall-windows-10-file-explorer/1492598#1492598) is my original post:

[How do I reinstall Windows 10 File Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1492576/how-do-i-reinstall-windows-10-file-explorer/1492598#1492598)

It IS NOT a reinstall of the file explorer.  It is wiping the data you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Folder views are saved i the registry in numerically-named subkeys of the key:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

That subkey can have up to three subkeys: `ComDlg`, `ComDlgLegacy`, and `Shell`.

Those will each have a GUID-named subkey with the GUID corresponding to one of the FolderType iDs:

```
Name                                   Value                       
----                                   -----                       
{71D642A9-F2B1-42cd-AD92-EB9300C7CC0A} StorageProviderPictures     
{DD61BD66-70E8-48dd-9655-65C5E1AAC2D1} StorageProviderDocuments    
{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9} CompressedFolder            
{fbb3477e-c9e4-4b3b-a2ba-d3f5d3cd46f9} Documents.Library           
{4F01EBC5-2385-41f2-A28E-2C5C91FB56E0} StorageProviderGeneric      
{e053a11a-dced-4515-8c4e-d51ba917517b} UserFiles.SearchResults     
{da3f6866-35fe-4229-821a-26553a67fc18} Generic.LibraryFolder       
{d674391b-52d9-4e07-834e-67c98610f39d} Programs                    
{de4f0660-fa10-4b8f-a494-068b20b22307} ControlPanelCategory        
{94d6ddcc-4a68-4175-a374-bd584a510b78} Music                       
{524ddb2b-2a4f-43b8-b8fe-e91ef9d8ba69} Contacts.Library            
{0c3794f3-b545-43aa-a329-c37430c58d2a} ControlPanelAllItems        
{0b0ba2e3-405f-415e-a6ee-cad625207853} Searches                    
{db2a5d8f-06e6-4007-aba6-af877d526ea6} AccountPictures             
{885a186e-a440-4ada-812b-db871b942259} Downloads                   
{36011842-dccc-40fe-aa3d-6177ea401788} Documents.SearchResults     
{7d49d726-3c21-4f05-99aa-fdc2c9474656} Documents                   
{4dcafe13-e6a7-4c28-be02-ca8c2126280d} Pictures.SearchResults      
{59BD6DD1-5CEC-4d7e-9AD2-ECC64154418D} UsersLibraries.SearchResults
{ef87b4cb-f2ce-4785-8658-4ca6c63e38c6} StartMenu                   
{631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed} Videos.Library              
{24ccb8a6-c45a-477d-b940-3382b9225668} HomeFolder                  
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4} Videos.SearchResults        
{978e0ed7-92d6-4cec-9b59-3135b9c49ccf} Music.LibraryFolder         
{91475fe5-586b-4eba-8d75-d17434b8cdf6} Communications              
{51294DA1-D7B1-485b-9E9A-17CFFE33E187} StorageProviderVideos       
{de2b70ec-9bf7-4a93-bd3d-243f7881d492} Contacts                    
{71689ac1-cc88-45d0-8a22-2943c3e7dfb3} Music.SearchResults         
{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8} Videos                      
{3D1D4EA2-1D8C-418a-BFF8-F18370157B55} OtherUsers.SearchResults    
{5f4eab9a-6833-4f61-899d-31cf46979d49} Generic.Library             
{3f2a72a7-99fa-4ddb-a5a8-c604edf61d6b} Music.Library               
{2c7bbec6-c844-4a0a-91fa-cef6f59cfda1} Printers                    
{20338b7b-531c-4aad-8011-f5b3db2123ec} Contacts.SearchResults      
{3f98a740-839c-4af7-8c36-5badfb33d5fd} Documents.LibraryFolder     
{292108be-88ab-4f33-9a26-7748e62e37ad} Videos.LibraryFolder        
{672ECD7E-AF04-4399-875C-0290845B6247} StorageProviderMusic        
{0b2baaeb-0042-4dca-aa4d-3ee8648d03e5} Pictures.Library            
{7fde1a1e-8b31-49a5-93b8-6be14cfa4943} Generic.SearchResults       
{654a1b99-8a4b-4e7b-a4e1-46378ad77a61} Contacts.LibraryFolder      
{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7} Generic                     
{B337FD00-9DD5-4635-A6D4-DA33FD102B7A} OtherUsers                  
{C4D98F09-6124-4fe0-9942-826416082DA9} UsersLibraries              
{CD0FC69B-71E2-46e5-9690-5BCD9F57AAB3} UserFiles                   
{b3690e58-e961-423b-b687-386ebfd83239} Pictures                    
{c1f8339f-f312-4c97-b1c6-ecdf5910c5c0} Pictures.LibraryFolder
```

So a saved `Generic` view looks like this:
[image]

When you assign a FolderType and select *`Also apply this template to all subfolders.`*, the GUID-named subkey acquires a sibling nnamed `Inherit`:
[image]

So, to "turn off" this behavior, delete the associated `Innherit` subkey ( and sign out & back in ).

You can search in Regedit.exe or use **PowerShell**:

```
'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' | gci -s | ? PSChildName -eq 'Inherit' | %{ gci $_.PSParentPath }
```

If you only used the setting on one folder, the search will be trivial. If you want to remove all instances, this PowerShell will do the trick:

```
'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' | gci -s | ? PSChildName -eq 'Inherit' | ri
```