# How to reset chosen folder type for a folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, reset, files-folders

In Windows there are several types of folder templates: General Items, Documents, Pictures, Music, Videos. User can apply any of them to a folder.

**I have a bunch of folders across the filesystem and I want to reset THEIR FOLDER TYPE all at once.** Depending on folder's content, Windows will automatically choose the proper folder type for all folders.

This [discussion](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7923-change-folder-template-windows-10-a.html#option3) explains how to reset a folder template, but it's not my case.

This [discussion](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/17707-reset-folder-view-settings-default-windows-10-a.html#option1) explains how to reset a folder view (table/tiles/list...), but it's also not my case.

---

I tested this on a clean system image and it worked:

[image: Disk Properties]

Folder types of all folders on a disk `D:` were reset to it's default type depending on content.

But the question is still relevant: why it's not working on my system and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [I wrote a script](https://superuser.com/questions/1492576/how-do-i-reinstall-windows-10-file-explorer/1492598#1492598) for another answer that will reset everything (for a different purpose) but it should work.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas it's weird, but it works on a sandbox windows instance but not on my PC. It's likely that I have registry corruption or something.

Comment: The whole point of that script was to fix registry corruption :^P .. oh well.. good luck fixing it.

Comment: @questeneer: You can try one of the scripts here: [Reset Folder View Settings](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-folder-views-bags-windows/) or [LesFerch/WinSetView: Globally Set Explorer Folder Views](https://github.com/LesFerch/WinSetView)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas well... I reinstalled Windows (deleted all partitions except primary disk D) and even now my folders on disk D have their previous types (I created test folder with pictures in and assigned music folder type. After reinstalling, folder type is music). How it's possible? I thought folder settings were saved in registry, but I was wrong.

Comment: The default choice of folder type is chosen by windows when you access it.  Explorer has some sort of algorithm to determine the type

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I know, and I want to apply this behaviour to the folder, which I already modified. For example, I created folder and put there some images, then windows automatically selected type 'pictures'. But after that, I selected type 'music' and now I want windows to autodetect it as 'pictures' again

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas please, watch this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1731136/reset-optimize-this-folder-for-property

Comment: I saw your question.  I get it (already got it).. the problem is that I would expect that data to be stored in Shell\Bags\* but I guess it isn't (as you tried that).  You could figure this out yourself using the SystemInternals process monitor, patience, and a whole lot of caffeine.  You will need to set it to `process is explorer.exe` and start weeding down the filters from there.  It will take a long time to figure out but it will indeed show you everything there is.